# Как по-русски пишется "праворуч"?

Tags: орфография, наречия

О романе ["Некто Финкельмайер"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3198959-kto-prototipy-poetov-manakina-i-prebylova-v-romane-nekto-finkelmajer.html).

> В 90-е, которые для меня прекрасные, а не ужасные, по книги можно было
>   ходить с огромным лукошком-чемоданом, и я приносила в дом тонны... И
>   вот стою я у прилавка центрального книжного магазина (полки-прилавки
>   ломятся) и вдруг случайно перехватываю взгляд молодого человека,
>   праворуч. По его взъезжающим бровям поняла: надо брать. И взяла. В
>   1990-м.

[**праворуч**](https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/uk-ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87)

> напра́во; впра́во; спра́ва; по пра́вую сто́рону

---

Ну наречие ж, ну мягкого ж знака хочу ж...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне тоже очень хочется поставить мягкий знак — на общих основаниях.
И есть для этого "показания".

*Это был поток иезуитской демагогии, из которого я впоследствии, то есть в нормальном состоянии, не смог воспроизвести ни одного пассажа, но, представ перед синклитом, во главе которого сидел Виноградов, а **праворучь** от него — Суровцев, я выдал такой нервно-паралитический спич, что они разинули рты.*
["Дружба народов". 2004, 9](http://magazines.russ.ru/druzhba/2004/9/a22.html)

*— Ага, — кивнул тот, глотая. — Наконечник-то я вытащил и перевязал, а всё одно — **праворучь** меча не вздынуть. Левой я, вестимо, тоже могу, только хуже* (В. Некрас. Нечаянная встреча).

.*..горели **праворучь** – Арбат и Смоленская площадь, **леворучь** – Тверская, Столешников, Петровка, Страстной, Трубная площадь, Цветной бульвар...* (Е. Крюкова. Юродивая).

P. S. Из Википедии:
*Константин Паустовский родился в семье железнодорожного статистика Георгия Максимовича Паустовского, имевшего украинско-польско-турецкие корни...

…отец отставной унтер-офицер II разряду из добровольцев, из мещан Киевской губернии...*

Вполне возможно, что "украинское происхождение" и повлияло на К. Г. Паустовского при написании слова "праворуч" – без мягкого знака.

Comment: Вот оно оно!!! ))) То, чего хочется-просится!!! )))

Comment: Мне на БВ ответ прислала филолог с тремя образованиями: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3205597-kak-po-russki-pishetsja-ukrainizm-narechie-pravoruch-pochemu-tak-prositsja-.html#answer9453431 - не разрешает писать с ерем. 8-(

Comment: Не, выше головы прыгать не собираюсь — где уж тут мне спорить с трёхкратным филологом! Я просто высказала свое мнение. Правда, вот у Даля нашлось о-очень похожее: _ОБ РУКУ, **обручь** с кем, нареч. под руку, под ручку, **подручь**, рука об руку._ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/286758/ОБ_РУКУ

Comment: Вот я ей щас как пришлю Вашу находку! А то она говорит: "Галочка, диахрония синхронии - не указ. Чем пользовался автор из "Дружбы народов", мы не знаем, возможно диалектным словом из южнорусских говоров. Но если слово берётся украинское, то мягкому знаку там неоткуда взяться".

Comment: Добавлю свое  мнение (очень личное, ни на что не претендующее). 1) Не стоит "критиковать" Паустовского и вспоминать о его украинском происхождении. Он просто зафиксировал реальную команду и не мог обойтись без этого слова. 2) Наречия обручь и подручь  также являлись падежными формами существительных (отсюда мягкий знак), но они не закрепились в русском языке. 3) А вот зачем в современных текстах использовать "праворуч", я не знаю. В словаре их нет, слово украинское, почему нельзя сказать "справа". Праворуч - не всем понятное слово, оно странно смотрится, что оно дает автору и читателю?

Comment: Sharon, что Вы, у меня и мысли не было — критиковать классика! Но ведь многих слов нет в официальных словарях, а мы их (слова и выражения) используем в своей речи, в том числе и заимствованные. Именно они иногда заостряют внимание читателя или слушателя, "обызюмливают" речь. Вы считаете мое ПЫ СЫ бестактным? Не хотела такой реакции — могу изничтожить.

Comment: Я знаю, что не было (Вы любите русскую литературу), поэтому я и написала в кавычках (ничего убирать не нужно, это же просто факты). Но Паустовский знал русскую грамоту, поэтому его выбор слова неслучаен. А вот почему современные авторы используют иностранные слова в русской записи, безо всяких кавычек или курсива - это непонятно, как бы они ни старались сделать предложение оригинальным (хотя, возможно, это ясно из контекста). У меня же вопрос прежде всего по оформлению. Я, к примеру, этого слова не знала, и некоторое время смотрела на предложение с недоумением.

Comment: Шаронушка, так ведь как моя филологиня сказала, по моей просьбе доредактировав ответ: если слово впрыгнуло прямиком из украинского - без еря, если из южнорусского диалекта - по правилам р. яз., т. е. с ерем, как Риммуля хочет. А слово - из моего ...э... подсознания, оно там торчало. То есть слышала, но ни на какой не на Украйне: в Москве. Могла в фильме, в передаче какой-нито... Сейчас, надеюсь, ещё одна от бога филолог мнение пришлёт.

Answer (score 1):

**А зачем Вам мягкий знак?** Конечно, есть правило, по которому только в ***уж, замуж, невтерпеж*** не пишется мягкий знак. Но это **формальное правило**, оно существует для удобства запоминания.

Наречий на шипящую с мягким знаком не так много, это ***прочь, сплошь, вскачь, настежь, точь-в-точь, невмочь, наотмашь, навзничь, напрочь.***

Мягкий знак в наречиях — это историческое написание, он обозначает, вероятно, бывший редуцированный гласный  в падежных формах существительного. Например, мягкий знак пишется в таких наречиях, как ***оземь, поодаль***, это тоже падежные формы.

Наречия ***праворуч*** в русских словарях нет, поэтому оно и **не соответствует формальному списку** наречий с мягким знаком и без него.

Пример

Прежде чем скомандовать ***праворуч*** («направо») или ***леворуч*** («налево»), он на несколько мгновений задумывался, припоминая команду, боясь ошибиться и спутать строй. [К. Г. Паустовский. Повесть о жизни. Начало неведомого века (1956)]